# i have got two android draw but i dont know why one work and second not

Tags: android, android-canvas

This code work and draw a ok:

```
   paintComponent(canvas);
        p=new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);

        for(int i=1;i<pointA.size();i++){
         int beginx=pointA.get(i-1).x, beginy=pointA.get(i-1).y,endx= pointA.get(i).x,endy= pointA.get(i).y;
         canvas.drawLine(beginx,beginy ,endx,endy, p);   
         Log.e("matej",beginx+"endy"+beginy+"endx"+endx+"endy"+endy);          

        }
        //canvas.drawLine(0, 181, xtest, ytest, p);
        //canvas.drawPath(path, p);
```

This code drawing not good all draw from one point but i dont know why:

```
paintComponent(canvas);
    p=new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    Path path1=new Path();
    path1.moveTo(pointA.get(0).x, pointA.get(0).y);
    for(int i=1;i<pointA.size();i=i+2){
     int beginx=pointA.get(i-1).x, beginy=pointA.get(i-1).y,endx= pointA.get(i).x,endy= pointA.get(i).y;
     path1.moveTo(pointA.get(i-1).x,pointA.get(i-1).y);
     path1.lineTo(pointA.get(i).x, pointA.get(i).y);   
     Log.e("matej","beginx "+beginx+"beginy "+beginy+"endx "+endx+"endy "+endy);
```

And finly i want to know what i fail in second code and i want know which code is faster :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

You declare lots of int values (beginx, beginy, etc) and don't actually use them, I'd suggest using them or deleting them for clarity.

You're also skipping out some points, IE

```
i = 1:
 moveTo(0, 0)
 lineTo(1, 1)

i = 3:
 moveTo(2, 2)
 lineTo(3, 3)
```

So no line is drawn between (1,1) and (2,2)

You also never call canvas.drawPath() so I'm not entirely sure how anything is getting drawn to the screen in the second example.